# Mono Compiling Error - Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ReferenceAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'System'

Tags: c#, mono

I am having trouble compiling my CSharp Mono application.

My Mono Version is 2.10.2

This is the error I am receiving

> Missing method .ctor in assembly /home/tmc/AcctTerm/System.dll, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ReferenceAssemblyAttribute
>   Can't find custom attr constructor image: /home/tmc/AcctTerm/System.dll mtoken: 0x0a000054
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ReferenceAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'System'.
>     at conAccountTerminator.cjcAccountTerminator..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
>     at conAccountTerminator.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

Any ideas?

edit: Adding Code;

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using MySql;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

namespace conAccountTerminator
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cjcAccountTerminator cjcAccountTerm = new cjcAccountTerminator();

            switch (args[0])
            {
                case "update":
                    cjcAccountTerm.LoginToMyBilling();
                    break;
                case "notepad":
                    cjcAccountTerm.UpdateCustomerData(args[1], args[2]);
                    break;
                case "terminate":
                    cjcAccountTerm.TerminateAccount(args[1]);
                    break;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any code to share? It looks like a custom attribute with not constructor.

Comment: some funny paths there, do you have a mono install in /home/tmc/AccTerm ? Looks like a strange place for System.dll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ReferenceAssemblyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.referenceassemblyattribute.aspx) is a recent attribute, first seen in FX 4.0.

Please ensure you're using Mono `'dmcs` compiler (or `mcs` with `-sdk=4`) to ensure you're linking with a version of `mscorlib.dll` (4.0) that has the attribute present.