# Could not load assembly System when using C++ and embedded mono to call to C# DLL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, mono

I have a C# sample code which is compiled into DLL using `xbuild` on Linux, e.g.:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
// ...

namespace MySamples
{
public class MyExample
{
    public static void test()
    {
        SortedSet<int> ss = new SortedSet<int>();
    } 
    // main function calls for test()
}
}
```

I can easily compile the sample code in a command line using `xbuild MyExample.csproj` into `exe` or `dll`, and then run using `mono MyExample.exe` - everything works fine and the sample code returns an expected result.

Now I want to make a call for the sample code from my C++ code, in particular to the `test()` function. I'm using mono runtime for that, and this is my C++ code:

```
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/object.h>
#include <mono/metadata/environment.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>
#include <mono/metadata/mono-config.h>

// ...
MonoDomain* domain = mono_jit_init("MyExample.dll");
MonoAssembly* assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "MyExample.dll");
mono_config_parse("MyExample.dll.config");

// mono is not installed in default locations:
mono_set_dirs("mypath/lib/mono", "mypath/etc/mono");

MonoImage* image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly);

MonoClass* klass = mono_class_from_name(image, "MySamples", "MyExample");
MonoObject* object = mono_object_new(domain, klass);
mono_runtime_object_init(object);

// call test()
MonoMethodDesc* mdesc = mono_method_desc_new(":test()", false);
MonoMethod* method = mono_method_desc_search_in_class(mdesc, klass);
mono_runtime_invoke(method, object, NULL, NULL);

// shutdown the runtime
mono_jit_cleanup (domain);
```

The C++ code, when run, returns an error of type:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' or one of its dependencies. ...

Since I know that if I run the same code using `mono` through the command line and it works, I feel like there is a problem with my C++ code and how I set up the mono runtime. I fixed a bunch of other errors by adding  `mono_set_dirs` since my Mono is not installed into the default directory (it's built from source).

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, if it matters, mono is built from source, CMake is used to compile my C++ code, and the `MyExample.dll.config` content:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>    
</configuration>
```

The `*.csproj` file include `System` in the following manner:

```
<Reference Include="System" />
```

Once again, I'm able to run the `test()` when using `mono` from command line (not from C++ project) with the C# settings as they are now.

Here is one more **strange thing**: if I replace the `SortedSet<int>` with  `List<int>`, it runs without throwing any errors. How can it be? - [they belong to the same namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.110).aspx). I checked other types, and when initializing most of them, an exception gets thrown.

Any ideas what is wrong here? I've been checking the [mono embedded docs](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=root:/embed) to try to find what could be wrong with my set up, but this is as far as I can reach. I'm beginner with C#, mono runtime and embedded mono.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873091/mono-compiling-error-could-not-load-type-system-runtime-compilerservices-refe?rq=1 - have you checked your mono compiler flags? Specifically `-sdk=4`

Comment: @JoshE I use `xbuild` which uses `csc`. But I can see that it links to the `mscorlib.dll` as reference. As I stated in the question, I feel like the problem is with C++ code, and not C#.

Comment: I understand - the reason I is b/c `System.Collections.Generic` is the reference that may be missing; the error message "covers" this with the offhand mention of `or one of its' dependencies`. Your csproj does not reference System.Collections.Generic, I also noticed. It may work in CLI due to lucky/DLL happens to be available to proc

Comment: @JoshE From my understanding, `System.Collections.Generic` is a namespace within the `System.dll`, so I do not have to include it in `csproj`. Tell me if I'm wring. When I look through mono DLLs in different versions (4.0, 4.5, 4.6.1, ...) I do not see there `System.Collections.Generic.dll` neither. That would mean that it actually cannot find the `System.dll` of a very certain version.

Comment: You're looking for `System.Collections.DLL`, which contains `System.Collections.Generic`. Did you see that DLL?

Comment: after looking through the mono docs, it does appear that System.Collections.Generic is indeed located within the System.dll. http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aSystem.Collections.Generic.SortedSet%601

Comment: did you add the csproj reference? `<Reference Include="System.Collections.Generic" />` You'll need that regardless of which assembly it's contained in

Comment: @JoshE hmm if I add it, I get a warning when running `xbuild` that the reference is not resolved. But I thought that `Reference Include` is not for namespaces but rather for libraries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was so trivial - I messed up the mono lib path in my C++ code. Apparently, you need to provide a prefix, and not the full path. So, in my case, I had to use:

```
mono_set_dirs("mypath/lib", "mypath/etc");
```

without using `mono` at the end.